# Python - How to compare strings to ensure they do not contain a double character, then save them to a file

Tags: python, replit

I am trying to make it so that if there are 2 words that have double letters in the loop, it will simply pass over them, or vice versa.

```
def initalizeData():
    try:
        words = open('words.txt', 'r')
    except FileNotFoundError:
        print("Check the file name or path.")
    else:
        list = open('final.txt', 'a')
        scriptwords = words.readlines()
        for w in scriptwords[:]:
            if len(w) >= 3 and len(w) <= 6:
                if w[:1] == 'a' or w[:1] == 'p':
                        for letter in scriptwords:
                           #this is where the statement should go, below is my attempt at it. 
                           #if scriptwords[letter] != scriptwords[(letter+1)]:
                                list.write(w.upper())
                        list.close()
```

I have tried the above, and the result is that Replit says:

```
File "main.py", line 14, in initalizeData
    if scriptwords[letter] != scriptwords[(letter+1)]:
TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not str
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can iterate through the letters of the word using the pattern below.  This will check that all pairs of letters are different in the word.  And I also changed the file name to `word_list` to avoid the name collision with `list`.

```
def initalizeData():
    try:
        words = open('words.txt', 'r')
    except FileNotFoundError:
        print("Check the file name or path.")
    else:
        word_list = open('final.txt', 'a')
        scriptwords = words.readlines()
        for w in scriptwords:
            if len(w) >= 3 and len(w) <= 6:
                if w[:1] == 'a' or w[:1] == 'p':
                        if all(l1 != l2 for l1,l2 in zip(w,w[1:])):
                            word_list.write(w.upper())
        word_list.close()
```

Comment: You explained it perfectly for me! This worked! Thank you so much!